# My desktop shows 3 yellow pixels

Tags: 20.04

From time to time my screen shows 3 yellow pixels in top right of the screen.
When i hover my mouse over it, it goes away these pixels apear near time here.

[image: 1]

Anyone knows why this is happening ?